# c++ sorting with custom compare function

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a vector of following type:

```
std::vector< std::pair< std::pair< int, int >, std::vector<float> > >  neighbors;
```

I would like to create sort the following vector as follows

```
std::sort( neighbors.begin(), neighbors.end(), myFunc(index) );
```

where,

```
bool myFunc( const std::pair< std::pair< int, int >, float > &a, const std::pair< std::pair< int, int >, float > &b, const int index ){
     return ( a.second[index] > b.second[index] );
}
```

I know that the syntax is wrong but I wish to provide an index for comparing only that element of the vector.

I am not sure how to pass this argument to myFunc.

Comment: Side Note: You may replace std::pair by more descriptive version

Comment: "comparing only that element" ... with what? you need two elements to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas:

```
std::sort(
    neighbors.begin(),
    neighbors.end(),
    [index](const std::pair< std::pair< int, int >, std::vector<float> > &a,  
            const std::pair< std::pair< int, int >, std::vector<float> > &b)
            { 
                 return ( a.second[index] > b.second[index] );
            }
);
```

See [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) for a detailled introduction.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `std::vector<float>`, not `float` for the second item of the outer `std::pair`

Comment: @MarcoA. Thanks. (Hm, I was sure I copypasted this part...)

Answer (score 1):

Pre-C++11 solution: use an object instance as a custom comparator

```
struct Comparator {
    Comparator(int index) : index_(index) {}
    bool operator () (const std::pair< std::pair< int, int >, std::vector<float> > &a,
                      const std::pair< std::pair< int, int >, std::vector<float> > &b) 
    {
        return ( a.second[index_] > b.second[index_] );
    }

    int index_;
};

sort(neighbors.begin(), neighbors.end(), Comparator(42));
```

C++11+ solution: use a lambda

```
std::sort(neighbors.begin(), neighbors.end(), [index]
                         (const std::pair< std::pair< int, int >, std::vector<float> > &a, 
                          const std::pair< std::pair< int, int >, std::vector<float> > &b) 
  { 
    return ( a.second[index] > b.second[index] );
  }
);
```

My advice: go for a lambda if you're allowed to use C++11 features. It's probably more elegant and readable.